# Is it possible to make tasker events conditional on whether I'm roaming?

Tags: tasker

Using 'Tasker', I have a task set up to dial my mobile phone balance enquiry number at 7pm each night, put in the right options, then hang up.  That results in a text being sent to me each evening with my remaining minutes - great!

However - I'm about to go abroad for three weeks and, left in its present state, it will rack up quite a bill if it does manage to dial.  How can I make this action conditional on roaming?  I considered using the location context but it crashes above certain ranges and isn't that reliable.

Answer (score 3):

If you are usually home at 7pm, you could make it conditional on the presence of your home Wifi network (using "Wifi Near") or a cell tower near you (using "Cell near"); if you use a dock at home, you could make it only fire when docked instead.

You could also make it dependent on a calendar and just set the dates for your trip now.

Comment: TomG:  Thanks.  Good workarounds - especially using wifi near as it's likely to be more robust than using location.  The dates idea is also nice but I go away quite frequently and it would be tough to maintain and expensive to forget!  I'm keen to hear any other means of detecting the roaming but will probably settle for your wifi idea Tom.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

There's a [Locale plugin](http://www.appbrain.com/app/locale-carrierid-plug-in/com.schmeisserweb.carrierstring) (that you can use in Tasker) that might handle your needs.

And here is [another plugin](http://www.appbrain.com/app/locale-phone-state-plug-in/com.androgone.locale.phonestate) for Locale.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

1. Profile context triggers on set variable CELLID with task check if ROAM matches off.
2. Set a variable ROAMING accordingly. Now you can have other profiles use the ROAMING variable to change settings like calls to accept or limiting data.

Tasker may not update CELLID instantly so you nasty be roaming a little while before it fires. Maybe a minute.

Try and let me know. Here is an export:

```
 <class cl="TaskerData" sr="">
    <tv>1.2u2m</tv>
    <class cl="Profile" sr="prof5">
        <cdate>1328389747604</cdate>
        <id>5</id>
        <mid0>25</mid0>
        <nme>Roaming Monitor</nme>
        <class cl="EventContext" sr="con0" ve="2">
            <code>3050</code>
            <pri>0</pri>
            <class cl="StringArg" sr="arg0" ve="3">
                <val>%CELLID</val>
            </class>
            <class cl="StringArg" sr="arg1" ve="3">
                <val></val>
            </class>
        </class>
    </class>
    <class cl="Task" sr="task25">
        <id>25</id>
        <pri>10</pri>
        <class cl="Action" sr="act0" ve="3">
            <code>37</code>
            <lhs>%ROAM</lhs>
            <op>2</op>
            <rhs>off</rhs>
        </class>
        <class cl="Action" sr="act1" ve="3">
            <code>547</code>
            <lhs>%ROAMING</lhs>
            <op>10</op>
            <rhs></rhs>
            <class cl="StringArg" sr="arg0" ve="3">
                <val>%ROAMING</val>
            </class>
            <class cl="StringArg" sr="arg1" ve="3">
                <val>1</val>
            </class>
            <class cl="IntArg" sr="arg2">
                <val>0</val>
            </class>
            <class cl="IntArg" sr="arg3">
                <val>0</val>
            </class>
        </class>
        <class cl="Action" sr="act2" ve="3">
            <code>43</code>
        </class>
        <class cl="Action" sr="act3" ve="3">
            <code>549</code>
            <lhs>%ROAMING</lhs>
            <op>9</op>
            <rhs></rhs>
            <class cl="StringArg" sr="arg0" ve="3">
                <val>%ROAMING</val>
            </class>
            <class cl="IntArg" sr="arg1">
                <val>0</val>
            </class>
        </class>
        <class cl="Action" sr="act4" ve="3">
            <code>38</code>
        </class>
    </class>
</class>
```